# Bounded function in $[0,1]$ without max and min.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Do we have a function $f$ defined in $[0, 1]$, which is bounded but has no maximum and minimum ?

I do know that $\arctan x$ can give me a hint, which is bounded without max and min but that's in $\mathbb R$.
Thanks!

---

**EDITED**:
Firstly thank all the answers that I received.
I would like to ask a little **additional question**: could we find some edited or mixed **trigonometric functions** to satisfy this problem?
If yes, a example please!
The reason is, that I got stuck with the idea of $\arctan x$ and other possible trigonometric functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Not if your function is continuous. Check for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a purely trigonometric function defined on $[0,1]$ that does not attain its max/min because it would be continuous and the extreme value theorem would apply.

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}(1-x)\sin(\frac 1x) &; x\in(0,1]\\
0 &; x=0
\end{cases}
$$
This function is *almost* a trigonometric function as you specified. It has $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)=1$ and $\inf_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)=-1$ but those values are not attained.

Answer (score 8):

$f(x)=x$ if $.25<x<.75$, and $f(x)=0.5$ otherwise

Answer (score 3):

The function $f$ defined below has $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)=1$ and $\inf_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)=-1$ but doesn't attain those values.
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac {(-1)^nn}{n+1} &; x=\frac 1n \text{   for $n\in\Bbb N$}\\
0 &; \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The key point is continuity, without that we can construct counterexample as

- $f(x)=x \quad x\in [0,1/2)$
- $f(x)=0 \quad x=1/2$
- $f(x)=1-x \quad x\in (1/2,1]$

Refer also to [**Extreme value theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).